# Cannot .Count() on IQueryable (NHibernate)

Tags: linq, nhibernate, count

I'm with an irritating problem. It might be something stupid, but I couldn't find out.

I'm using **Linq to NHibernate**, and I would like to count how many items are there in a repository. Here is a very simplified definition of my repository, with the code that matters:

```
public class Repository {
    private ISession session;
    /* ... */
    public virtual IQueryable<Product> GetAll() {
        return session.Linq<Product>();
    }
}
```

**All the relevant code in the end of the question.**

Then, to **count the items** on my repository, I do something like:

```
var total = productRepository.GetAll().Count();
```

The problem is that `total` is 0. Always. However there are items in the repository. Furthermore, I can `.Get(id)` any of them.

My **NHibernate log** shows that the following query was executed:

```
SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM [Product] this_ WHERE not (1=1)
```

That must be that "WHERE not (1=1)" clause the cause of this problem.

What can I do to be able `.Count()` the items in my repository?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Actually the repository.GetAll() code is a little bit different... and that might change something! It is actually a generic repository for Entities. Some of the entities implement also the ILogicalDeletable interface (it contains a single bool property "IsDeleted"). Just before the "return" inside the GetAll() method I check if if the Entity I'm querying implements ILogicalDeletable.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : Entity<TEntity, TId> {
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    ...
}

public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : Entity<TEntity, TId>

{
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        if (typeof (ILogicalDeletable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (TEntity)))
        {
            return session.Linq<TEntity>()
                .Where(x => (x as ILogicalDeletable).IsDeleted == false);
        }
        else
        {
            return session.Linq<TEntity>();
        }
    }
}

public interface ILogicalDeletable {
    bool IsDeleted {get; set;}
}

public Product : Entity<Product, int>, ILogicalDeletable
{ ... }

public IProductRepository : IRepository<Product, int> {}
public ProductRepository : Repository<Product, int>, IProductRepository {}
```

**Edit 2**: actually the `.GetAll()` is always returning an empty result-set for entities that implement the ILogicalDeletable interface (ie, it ALWAYS add a `WHERE NOT (1=1)` clause.

I think Linq to NHibernate does not like the typecast.

Comment: It sounds like the GetAll code is actually pretty important. Could you post it please?

Comment: It's there now. I think Linq to NHibernate converts "(x as ILogicalDeletable).IsDeleted == false" as "NOT (1=1)".

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this? I'm running into the same thing and can't use a filter in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got a soft delete model going on here, and you're trying to filter these out from being returned by the GetAll() method.  I agree with your analysis that NHibernate.Linq doesn't properly process the typecast, but you may want to try replacing this with a [query filter](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-filtering).

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
  if (typeof(ILogicalDeletable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
  {
    return session.Linq<TEntity>().OfType<ILogicalDeletable>()
      .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Cast<TEntity>();
  }

  return session.Linq<TEntity>();
}
```

Try that.